# How to set Oracle NLS_LANG when using JPA

Tags: oracle, jpa, nls-lang

I am using JPA to access an Oracle database which has its encoding set to ISO-8859-1.

How do I set NLS_LANG using JPA to receive data in the correct encoding?

I suspect it should be set somewhere in the persistence context XML.

Comment: You should **not** rely on a special value for NLS_LANG (and the implicit conversion that comes with it). Use the approriate format masks e.g. in `to_date()` or `to_char()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDBC driver takes care of everything. It knows what the encoding value is and uses the appropriate encoding without any action on your part.

Comment: AFAIK the driver uses the default locale from the JVM (which can be set using `-Duser.locale`) - but still: no production code should ever rely on a specific setting for NLS_LANG

Comment: You're probably right. My answer was more concerned with the encoding. I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks. I caused the special characters to be wrong myself. Hence no need to try to change connection settings anymore.